# What do you call a microphone that is held beside the face?

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds

I don't know a term denoting a microphone usually held on speaker's side of the face. See following image that shows in white:

[image: example image]

I googled images pertaining to the types of microphone, but that did not help. It shown me following results, that does not include the thing, of which I want the term.

[image: types of microphone]

After encountering such types, I had a doubt, whether the term which I want to know is just "microphone" or not.

Sample sentence can be:

I saw Sandeep Maheshwari giving a comprehensive lecture in front of a large audience via a device held on his face, called a _____ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a "(flex) mic boom."  The tip can be referred to as a "microphone."   Though a headset boom is much smaller than a traditional microphone boom, it's still called a boom for some reason.

I am also seeing "wireless headset microphone" as a better description.

The "boom" term seems to be more  for wired headsets.

Comment: They're not always wireless, but I think "headset microphone" is a good description.

Comment: I think technically the boom is just the "arm" portion that positions the mic away from the base.  A flex boom is a boom that is flexible.  "Headset" is a term for the combination of a microphone and earpieces.   The term [headworn mic](https://www.google.com/search?q=headworn+microphone&source=lnms&tbm=isch) is  appropriate for the piece OP is looking for.

Comment: Didn't they used to be nicknamed "Madonna mics"?